# Get Input path from job conf in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am setting a path as input location to conf

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("path/to/folder"));
```

How can I retrieve this location back from conf as I am trying to implement my own RecordReader

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property set by this call is `map.input.dir`, so this should work for you:

```
conf.get("map.input.dir");
```

On a side note, your record reader should act upon the input split it is given in the `initialize(InputSplit, TaskAttemptContext)` method, as the folder you pass in setInputPath will actually resolve to a number of input splits, typically one for each file in the folder (and possible multiple input splits for larger, splittable files).

`FileInputFormat` based input formats are passed a `FileSplit` to the initialize method, and you should be able to pull out the actual file to be processed from the `FileSplit.getPath()` method.

Comment: To augment the answer by @ChrisWhite, it can also be under the hashkey "mapred.input.dir".